How can I adjust the hover effect to show price and indicator info directly on the stock chart when using Vite.js?
I referred to this example on CodePen using react-financial-charts library, specifically attached here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-financial-charts-demo-forked-zw4o4?file=%2Findex.js. However, when I re-coded it using Vite.js and ran the file, the chart mostly displayed like the CodePen demo, except for the hover effect as shown in the example. Where did I go wrong?
My code here
App.jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { format } from "d3-format";
import { timeFormat } from "d3-time-format";
import {
  elderRay,
  ema,
  discontinuousTimeScaleProviderBuilder,
  Chart,
  ChartCanvas,
  CurrentCoordinate,
  BarSeries,
  CandlestickSeries,
  ElderRaySeries,
  LineSeries,
  MovingAverageTooltip,
  OHLCTooltip,
  SingleValueTooltip,
  lastVisibleItemBasedZoomAnchor,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CrossHairCursor,
  EdgeIndicator,
  MouseCoordinateX,
  MouseCoordinateY,
  ZoomButtons,
  withDeviceRatio,
  withSize
} from "react-financial-charts";
import { initialData } from "./data.jsx";
// import ChartExample from "./Chart.jsx";

const rotateArray2 = function (nums, k) {
  // reverse helper function
  function reverse(arr, start, end) {
    while (start < end) {
      [arr[start], arr[end]] = [arr[end], arr[start]];
      start++;
      end--;
    }
  }

  k %= nums.length;

  reverse(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
  reverse(nums, 0, k - 1);
  reverse(nums, k, nums.length - 1);

  return nums;
};

const App = () => {
  const ScaleProvider = discontinuousTimeScaleProviderBuilder().inputDateAccessor(
    (d) => new Date(d.date)
  );
  const height = 700;
  const width = 900;
  const margin = { left: 0, right: 48, top: 0, bottom: 24 };

  const ema12 = ema()
    .id(1)
    .options({ windowSize: 12 })
    .merge((d, c) => {
      d.ema12 = c;
    })
    .accessor((d) => d.ema12);

  const ema26 = ema()
    .id(2)
    .options({ windowSize: 26 })
    .merge((d, c) => {
      d.ema26 = c;
    })
    .accessor((d) => d.ema26);

  const elder = elderRay();

  const rotateArray2 = function (nums, k) {
    // reverse helper function
    function reverse(arr, start, end) {
      while (start < end) {
        [arr[start], arr[end]] = [arr[end], arr[start]];
        start++;
        end--;
      }
    }

    k %= nums.length;

    reverse(nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    reverse(nums, 0, k - 1);
    reverse(nums, k, nums.length - 1);

    return nums;
  };

  const calculatedData = elder(ema26(ema12(rotateArray2(initialData))));
  const { data, xScale, xAccessor, displayXAccessor } = ScaleProvider(
    rotateArray2(initialData)
  );
  const pricesDisplayFormat = format(".2f");
  const max = xAccessor(data[data.length - 1]);
  const min = xAccessor(data[Math.max(0, 0)]);
  const xExtents = [min, max + 5];

  const gridHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const elderRayHeight = 100;
  const elderRayOrigin = (_, h) => [0, h - elderRayHeight];
  const barChartHeight = gridHeight / 4;
  const barChartOrigin = (_, h) => [0, h - barChartHeight - elderRayHeight];
  const chartHeight = gridHeight - elderRayHeight;
  const yExtents = (data) => {
    return [data.high, data.low];
  };
  const dateTimeFormat = "%d %b";
  const timeDisplayFormat = timeFormat(dateTimeFormat);

  const barChartExtents = (data) => {
    return data.volume;
  };

  const candleChartExtents = (data) => {
    return [data.high, data.low];
  };

  const yEdgeIndicator = (data) => {
    return data.close;
  };

  const volumeColor = (data) => {
    return data.close > data.open
      ? "rgba(38, 166, 154, 0.3)"
      : "rgba(239, 83, 80, 0.3)";
  };

  const volumeSeries = (data) => {
    return data.volume;
  };

  const openCloseColor = (data) => {
    return data.close > data.open ? "#26a69a" : "#ef5350";
  };



  return (
    <ChartCanvas
      height={height}
      ratio={3}
      width={width}
      margin={margin}
      data={data}
      displayXAccessor={displayXAccessor}
      seriesName="Data"
      xScale={xScale}
      xAccessor={xAccessor}
      xExtents={xExtents}
      zoomAnchor={lastVisibleItemBasedZoomAnchor}
    >
      <Chart
        id={2}
        height={barChartHeight}
        origin={barChartOrigin}
        yExtents={barChartExtents}
      >
        <BarSeries fillStyle={volumeColor} yAccessor={volumeSeries} />
      </Chart>
      <Chart id={3} height={chartHeight} yExtents={candleChartExtents}>
        <XAxis showGridLines showTickLabel={false} />
        <YAxis showGridLines tickFormat={pricesDisplayFormat} />
        <CandlestickSeries />
        <LineSeries yAccessor={ema26.accessor()} strokeStyle={ema26.stroke()} />
        <CurrentCoordinate
          yAccessor={ema26.accessor()}
          fillStyle={ema26.stroke()}
        />
        <LineSeries yAccessor={ema12.accessor()} strokeStyle={ema12.stroke()} />
        <CurrentCoordinate
          yAccessor={ema12.accessor()}
          fillStyle={ema12.stroke()}
        />
        <MouseCoordinateY
          rectWidth={margin.right}
          displayFormat={pricesDisplayFormat}
        />
        <EdgeIndicator
          itemType="last"
          rectWidth={margin.right}
          fill={openCloseColor}
          lineStroke={openCloseColor}
          displayFormat={pricesDisplayFormat}
          yAccessor={yEdgeIndicator}
        />
        <MovingAverageTooltip
          origin={[8, 24]}
          options={[
            {
              yAccessor: ema26.accessor(),
              type: "EMA",
              stroke: ema26.stroke(),
              windowSize: ema26.options().windowSize
            },
            {
              yAccessor: ema12.accessor(),
              type: "EMA",
              stroke: ema12.stroke(),
              windowSize: ema12.options().windowSize
            }
          ]}
        />

        <ZoomButtons />
        <OHLCTooltip origin={[8, 16]} />
      </Chart>
      <Chart
        id={4}
        height={elderRayHeight}
        yExtents={[0, elder.accessor()]}
        origin={elderRayOrigin}
        padding={{ top: 8, bottom: 8 }}
      >
        <XAxis showGridLines gridLinesStrokeStyle="#e0e3eb" />
        <YAxis ticks={4} tickFormat={pricesDisplayFormat} />

        <MouseCoordinateX displayFormat={timeDisplayFormat} />
        <MouseCoordinateY
          rectWidth={margin.right}
          displayFormat={pricesDisplayFormat}
        />

        <ElderRaySeries yAccessor={elder.accessor()} />

        <SingleValueTooltip
          yAccessor={elder.accessor()}
          yLabel="Elder Ray"
          yDisplayFormat={(d) =>
            `${pricesDisplayFormat(d.bullPower)}, ${pricesDisplayFormat(
              d.bearPower
            )}`
          }
          origin={[8, 16]}
        />
      </Chart>
      <CrossHairCursor />
    </ChartCanvas>
  );
};

export default App;

main.jsx
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)

data.jsx I follow by example in codepen I show before
I want to  debug and fix the chart more friendly and beautifully
